# Coreplot scroll interferes with plotSymbolWasSelectedAtRecordIndex

Tags: ios, core-plot, scatter-plot

I'm showing a modal popup in my app when somebody taps on one of the points in my scatter plot. The problem is, when you want to drag the plot and accidentially touch one of the points, the modal popup appears, which is kinda annoying. Is there any way to get rid of this behaviour? Seems like the `plotSymbolWasSelectedAtRecordIndex` gets fired on a TouchDown event instead of TouchUp.

Thanks.

Comment: Does it happen only at iOs 7 ? I had a similar issue with scroll view at iOs 7 and ended up with replacing override of `touchDown` with `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

Comment: No this is also on iOS 6 and 5

Comment: Interesting, probably core plot has another core issue. You can still try to do the same thing: at core plot source code remove `touchDown` override and detect taps with `UITapGestureRecognizer`, it should help.